# EPPlus: dynamic pivot table using external connection

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to generate an Excel workbook from C#.

I read that EPPlus is supporting pivot tables, but I would need something like the Excel-interop property [PivotTable.SourceData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable.sourcedata.aspx), to generate a dynamic sheet which updates its data using the given connection. Do you know if this feature is available in EPPlus?

Could you please help me in setting up an external connection on a pivot object? I've written a 'create connection' method using pure OpenXML, but I'm having some difficulties in associating this connection to a pivot...

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, i'm afraid. I tried to post the question also on EPPlus website, but with no luck...